# Photos not taken on any of our devices showing up on my Photo Stream

Tags: iphone, photo-stream

Photos that were not taken on any of our devices are showing up on my Photo Stream. My son recently had his iPhone stolen, and he had Photo Stream turned on, so I am guessing that the photos are coming from the person who stole his phone.  We reported it stolen with AT&T, and erased it on the Find My iPhone app, so what else needs to be done so that we no longer get those photos?

Comment: So you have a Photo ID of the person who stole the phone?

Comment: Does your son use iCloud? Did he have the FindMyPhone app installed? If so, you should be able to go to iCloud.com, log in and find, even erase (wipe) the device. If not, contact information, personal details, credit card info are all at risk. I suggest getting him to change all risky numbers. Perhaps notify contacts to look out for spam/rubbish/malware etc.

Answer (score 1):

If your son had the FindMyPhone app installed,  you should be able to go to iCloud.com, log in and find and erase (wipe) the device. If it ahas been some time, contact information, personal details, credit card info are all at risk. I suggest getting him to change all risky numbers. Perhaps notify contacts to look out for spam/rubbish/malware etc.

Comment: OP says they erased it using the Find My Phone app. Also the credit card number itself is not at risk. The card may have been charged but only for things that can be purchased using an Apple ID, since once the card number is input you can't get the whole number back out. I didn't downvote because your answer contains some *generally* useful info for stolen phones, but it is mostly irrelevant for this question.

Comment: I understood that'd they'd erased it. (or thought they did). Wouldn't  the device have to have the OP's iCloud info to have images show up on their photo stream? If that is correct, then not everything was erased.  I should have explained myself better.

Answer (score 0):

Change the password on your Apple ID (and it wouldn't hurt to change the email address used as the login name, either). This should prevent that device from being able to access it any further.